# Avoid cast in java (Generics)

Tags: java, generics

Is the a way the cast below can be avoided?

```
//Is there a way this can be implemented so the cast is not necessary? 
FooService fooService = new FooService();
Foo f = (Foo)fooService.findById(id);

public class FooService extends DomainServiceImpl<Foo> {
}

public class DomainService<T extends Persistable>{

   private Class<T> type;

   public void findById(long id) {
      domainDao.findById(id, type);
   }
}
```

edit: Still have to cast

```
public T findById(long id) {
    return (T) fooDao.findById(id, type);
}
```

Comment: Yes, return T in your findById method and not void as you are doing now. Does this even compile?

Comment: @Matthias you should write this as an answer

Comment: I am not sure this is the only problem as there are types missing in the posted code.

Comment: I dont see the point to downvote this question

Comment: @Matthias I wrote this now so I dont think it compile. It was just to show

Comment: @Matthias I did the change. Still need the cast.

Comment: @user874774, don't show code with error. It distracts user from original problem

Comment: It won't compile. Just for the parenthesis in *DomainService* class definition, and by the fact that you try to get an object from a method returning void.

Comment: Please just.... pretend that it compile if possible..... Getting it to compile is not my issue @dooxe

Comment: @user874774 Depending on how you retrieve the object in your `findById`method you might have to cast there, but the cast in the 2nd line of your code sample is prevented by using `T` as a return value of your method. My answer is also showing a way of avoiding the cast in the generic method, it however assumes you have a default constructor and want to create a new object, so is very specific to your situation and might not be fitting

Comment: If you don't like it, don't cast - @SuppressWarnings('rawTypes') xD

Comment: The question whether a cast is necessary depends on how the referenced `fooDao.findById` method is defined. But that method is completely missing in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, before this gets a tree of comments I will post a solution which might fit your needs. You'll have to adapt it to your specific problem however.

The main idea is, that the method `findById` is returning the generic type `T` so you do not need the type cast in your code.

```
class Solution {
  static class Foo extends Persistable {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    FooService fooService = new FooService();
    Foo f = fooService.findById(0l);
  }

  static class FooService extends DomainService<Foo> {
    FooService() {
      type = Foo.class;
    }
  }

  static class Persistable {
  }

  static class DomainService<T extends Persistable> {

    Class<T> type;

    public T findById(long id) {
      try {
        return this.type.newInstance();
      }
      catch (InstantiationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
type.cast(object);
```

to avoid the warning.

Note that this still might throw a ClassCastException.

If you're not sure that the object can be cast, check with:

```
if (type.isInstance(object)){
    return type.cast(object);
} else {
   ... 
}
```